# limitation with csv bulk insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a functionality with csv file upload. Functionality is working if csv is having nearly 30k rows. But whenever csv file will have more than 30k rows then bulk insert is not working. Below is my code for reading csv and inserting into table.

```
$csvfile = fopen($file, 'r');
$i = 0;
$data4 = "";
while (!feof($csvfile))
{
    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
    $csv_array = explode(";", $csv_data[$i]);
    $data4.= "('".$csv_array[2]."', '".$csv_array[4]."', '".$csv_array[0]."','".$csv_array[1]."'),";  
}
$i++;
fclose($csvfile);
$data4 = substr($data4,0,-1);
$sql = "INSERT INTO csv_table(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`) VALUES $data4"; 
mysqli_query($mysqliConn,$sql);
```

Only I am  having issue when I have records more than 30k. Please suggest me changes here.
    Thanks in advance

Comment: Try checking for errors, such as looking for [mysqli_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Beyond that, we need to know *how* it's not working.

Comment: I am using jquery file upload here, simply I am getting internal server error 500

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

**Pro tip:** "Not working," of course, can mean anything from "my server caught fire and my data center burned to the ground," to "all my values were changed to `42`," to "the operation had no effect."  *Understand your errors. Check the errors that come back from operations like `mysqli_query()`*.

That being said...

You're slurping up your entire CSV file's contents and jamming it into a single text string.  It's likely that method falls over when the csv file is too long.

There's a limit on the length of a MySQL query. It's large, but not infinite, and it's set both by a server parameter and the server configuration.  Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

php can run out of memory as well.

How to fix?  Process your CSV file not all at once, but in chunks of fifty rows or so. Once you've read fifty rows, do an insert.

**Pro tip 2:** *Sanitize your input data.* What will happen to your table if somebody puts a row like this in an uploaded CSV file?

```
"bwahahahaha!'; -- DROP TABLE csv_table;", "something", "somethingelse"
```

You may be OK. But do you want to run a risk like this?

Be aware that the public net is crawling with cybercriminals, and somebody will detect and exploit this kind of vulnerability in days if you leave it running.

Comment: one internal system will generate this csv, so this will not happen.

Comment: with respect, these will be the famous last words of @user3408779.

Comment: Right, I agree what you said